# Is there a form to know the PostgreSQL version using nmap?

Tags: databases, nmap, network-scanners

I tried using the following command:

```
nmap -p 5432 -v --script pgsql-brute myhost
```

But I got no output related to the pgsql script nor the dbms version.

Comment: I think nmap does not get this information from postgresql, if some version have some bugs it can be determined by testing this bugs, and if is there you can say wow probably the version is: 9.1 for ex.

Answer (score 1):

The [pgsql-brute script](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/pgsql-brute.html) performs password guessing (brute-forcing) against PostgreSQL databases. It does not retrieve any version information or display anything but successfully-guessed usernames and passwords.

A more useful command for getting information from a PostgreSQL database would be:

```
nmap -p 5432 -sV myhost
```

This performs [service and application version detection](https://nmap.org/book/vscan.html) on the database, and results in output like:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE    VERSION
5432/tcp open  postgresql PostgreSQL DB 9.1.12 - 9.1.14
```

This is based on a line number in an error response to a probe to that port, and can usually narrow down the version to one of a handful of minor versions.

Answer (score 0):

In nmap, you should know the following:

When you want to run a protocol-specific NSE script, such as pgsql-brute (or the generic `brute` NSE script), nmap will need the version information to match the port or be able to detect it, i.e.,

`nmap -v --script brute -sV -p 5432 <ip>`

or nmap can skip version detection if the `+` character is utilized -- thus forcing the script to run, e.g.,

`nmap -v --script +pgsql-brute -p 5432 <ip>`